# Determine prop types from a JSX.Element

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[Ts Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiTAApQRgDO2AUgMoAa2y6MAogDZIhy8AL5wAZjRBwA5FFQZpAKEXAKSKGPRI4AFSR0YhYmQrVadXIrhxS+XsDQBrAFxwAFAEo4AXgB8cADcIYAATRWFlNFIDXX14b3c8W3snOGFXPQMjSBMqGnovPzgAHgAjAFcYGFIbEjsHR28cZIbhXzQUx2KAegqq0l9I6PgAKzoADz4BIR8SzPgWpybPH39pGDjpNLhu-27uuBZWADopwQplfbgAGQgIR1UAc3FoOBQ4AHcUAE84arhHkh4AADebZUhCMz0YHiSR-AAW2iOp345xBY0mqKEwMUVxg3zA2jEEHKJBCOgJ2gS+MJEDEcAxZyExxpSAA2tIwPk6NIALo7A4oEjfXEHVkvUnkymzVl0hkTJkUFnSq5CkV46XEyUUwmzcG5KF0Yqy+mMrFKrnmPaC4Wiv6aklknVUghEHKQ7nGylys3TJWs61vW0a3Vap3ShL6j3mL2000K80wZWEjmW+h8wNqu3isNS3WRt0Q0yek3yzF+mCBxXwEIQfRwEgQeB0FAwYB0MS-KIkAxQFCqGDZh3aiOu4zR+ixpA+hMV5NIQPI6uXMXSgDiQKjxZjOn8CR0cCQ4w2ZIsnAwxy3MGdxVUYnUcEo-gAPoh5Emr7eSPeoI--AB+R84FcMgAnUIdQ0dPMXQ3QxCwNEtvXjcs0UDUDwKAA)

Is it possible to determine the type of a function component's props when all you're given is the JSX.Element?

In the following example the component props and component are defined locally, so of course I could use `typeof Test` but I'm curious about getting the same information if all I have to go from is the actual JSX.Element (`jsxElement` below)

```
import React, { ComponentProps, JSX, ReactElement } from 'react'

interface TestComponentProps {
  onClick: () => void
}

const Test = ({ onClick }: TestComponentProps) =>
  <button onClick={onClick}>click</button>

// How do I extract the prop types/TestComponentProps from JUST this
const jsxElement = <Test onClick={() => 'test' } /> //JSX.Element
```

I have tried all of the following without any luck.

```
// type foundType = typeof jsxElement.type['props'] // any
// type foundType = typeof jsxElement.type // any
// type foundType = ComponentProps<typeof jsxElement.props> // any
// type foundType = ComponentProps<typeof jsxElement.type> // any
// type foundType = ComponentProps<typeof jsxElement.type['props']> // any
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

**`type foundType = React.ComponentProps<typeof jsxElement>`**

if still no luck, there is last resort as

`type GetComponentProps<T> = T extends React.ComponentType<infer P> | React.Component<infer P> ? P : never`

`type foundType = GetComponentProps<typeof jsxElement>`

and also
`type Props = typeof MyComponent.defaultProps;`

Comment: Neither work, the first says `Element` does not satisfy the constraint of ComponentProps, and with your custom type it just returns `never`. `typeof MyComponent.defaultProps` can;t work for this question but if I had the pointer to `MyComponent` none of this would be needed